# How to construct a triangle with $BC=7.5$ cm.
$\angle ABC$=$60$° and $AC-AB=1.5$ cm.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

> How to construct a triangle with $BC=7.5$ cm.
>   $\angle ABC$=$60$° and $AC-AB=1.5$ cm.

At first I constructed $BC$ then $\angle ABC$ ,but I don't know what to do next. Please help me.

Comment: How about utilising the cosine rule, where $AC=AB+1.5$

Comment: @Raptor please explain more. Give me more hint. Cosine rule over which triangle?

Comment: The triangle $\triangle ABC$, so $BC^2+AB^2-2 \cdot AB \cdot BC\cos \angle ABC=AC^2$

Comment: Thanks! I have done the problem!

Comment: @Raptor: The task is to construct, not to calculate the sides of the triangle. You are using a cannot to kill an ant.

Comment: @Sufaid Saleel, I think the question is wrong. it must be $AB-AC=1.5$ in this case $AB=12$ and $AC=12-1.5=10.5$.and the construction is easy now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the cosine rule is not the way to solve this problem simply and efficiently. This is a problem about construciton, not trigonometry. You are not supposed to calculate values that are not given.

Suppose that triangle $ABC$ is the solution. Draw a circular arc $l$ with center at point $A$ and radius $AC$ until it meets the ray $AB$ in point $C'$. Obviously $BC'$=$AC-AB$, which is given. So it is possible to construct triangle $BCC'$: we know $BC$, $BC'$ and $\angle CBC'=180^\circ-\angle ABC=120^\circ$.

Triangle $ACC'$ is isosceles so the point $A$ has to be on the median $n$ of segment $CC'$. After the construciton of triangle $CBC'$ just extend $C'B$ until it meets the median of $CC'$. The intersection point is actually your point $A$.

Problems like this one do not need trigonometry at all.

[image]